# How to control checkbox Situation in List View asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, checkbox

I'm control check box checked or not in GridView like in the below

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");

                if (cb.Checked == true)
                {
                    if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
                    {
                           //Some Stuf..

                    }
                }
              }
```

But i can't find the way how to control check box in list view Because Listview doesn't have extension "Row" like in the grid view could you help me about it?

My listview code written in the below

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server">

             <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </ul>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                        <b>City: </b><span class="city"><%# Eval("eeee") %></span><br />
                        <b>Postal Code: </b><span class="postal"><%# Eval("dddd") %></span><br />
                        <b>Country: </b><span class="country"><%# Eval("cccc")%></span><br />
                        <b>Phone: </b><span class="phone"><%# Eval("bbbb")%></span><br />
                        <b>Fax: </b><span class="fax"><%# Eval("aaaa")%></span><br />
            </li>


        </ItemTemplate>

            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                    <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                </div>
                <div style="text-align: center;background-color: #FFCC66;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #333333;">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                            <asp:NumericPagerField />
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>

        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            Sonuç Bulunamadı
        </EmptyDataTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (ListViewItem row in ListView2.Items)
    {            
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if( cb != null)
            {
                if (cb.Checked == true)
                {
                       //Some Stuf..
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that's what i'm looking for =) . It's very very helpfull to me